# GKE shielded nodes enabled by default when disabled in terraform

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am seeing a difference between two GCP projects when deploying the same terraform google_container_cluster configuration for GKE cluster deployments.

The terraform google_container_cluster configuration explicitly disables shielded nodes:

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "csurv-cluster" {
   ...
   enable_shielded_nodes       = false
   ...
```

This terraform configuration is used to provision clusters across a number of projects, and with the exception of one project the clusters are provisioned with shielded nodes disabled.

One project does not respect this configuration and provisions shielded nodes when the clusters are initially provisioned.

Later when reconnecting to the cluster for maintenance the difference between requested and provisioned configurations is detected and this results in the nodes being repaired to match the terraform configuration which results in an unnecessary outage.

Any suggestions as to why this is happening and what I can do to resolve?

Comment: It doesn't looks like an issue with GKE. As long as you are not creating a '[GKE Autopilot clusters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview)'(For GKE Autopilot clusters, the Shielded GKE nodes feature is enabled by default and cannot be overridden) or using a '[shielded VM](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints#constraints-for-specific-services)(as suggested by the other community member)' constraint, you should be able to create a cluster by disabling the Shielded GKE node feature.

Comment: To confirm whether the issue is related within the GKE cluster, I would recommend you to deploy a test cluster(using the exact same configuration from your terraform file) directly using gcloud or UI and see if it is allowing to create that cluster with out the Shielded GKE node feature. If it does allows you to create one such cluster, the issue could be lying within your terraform code.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you have Shielded VMs enabled as an organizational policy on that one project? Policy list is [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints#constraints-supported-by-multiple-google-cloud-services).

You can check this through IAM > Org Policies > Choose project for the top blue drop down > Choose policy constraint from the filter search bar > Click policy and see if it is enforced on that project.